# Get MIN and MAX values from group of Dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
|date_start|time_start|time_end|
|2020-06-01|08:36     |12:34   |
|2020-06-01|12:40     |14:36   |
|2020-06-01|16:45     |20:00   |
|2020-06-02|09:36     |12:34   |
|2020-06-02|15:36     |19:44   |
|2020-06-03|12:36     |14:54   |
|2020-06-03|18:36     |23:04   |
```

I need a query to return the MIN(time_start) and MAX(time_end) from each date
so for above table the result must be

```
DATE         MIN  MAX
2020-06-01 08:36 20:00
2020-06-02 09:36 19:44
2020-06-03 12:36 23:04
```

I tried with subqueries but not succeeded to have a result.

Comment: Please show the queries that you tired.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT date_start as DATE, MAX(time_start), MIN(time_end)
FROM
date_table
GROUP BY date_start;
```

Comment: it was so easy and i made it inside my mind so complicated. Thx for the quick answer !!!

Comment: Happy to help!!